# Delete files in local folder using DeleteAsync function of StorageFile

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am going over all the files in my Data folder and none of them are being deleted. I'm not sure but I think I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is:

```
private async void pageRoot_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> thefiles;

    var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    thefiles = await localFolder.GetFilesAsync();

    for(int i = 1; i < thefiles.Count; i++)
    {
        await thefiles[i].DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.Default);
    }
}
```

Am I doing this right? Any ideas why this isn't working? I do not receive any compiletime or runtime errors.

Comment: sorry buddy....just in enthusiasm provided the wrong answer

Comment: No worries @UthistranS. I've done that too lol. Sometimes I'm like "Oh! I know this!" then later I see downvotes, then I'm like "ohhh, it's different..." :P

Answer (score 2):

You have a different problem since the breakpoints are never being hit, but I just wanted to mention...

Your first file will never be deleted because you are initializing i to 1.  Initialize it to 0 instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i < thefiles.Count; i++)
{
    await thefiles[i].DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.Default);
}
```

Comment: Use foreach instead of for, it avoids silly mistakes like starting from the wrong index. FYI: in .NET you can create arrays that do not start at index 0 (the default is 0, but you can create one that starts at 10 or any other value, interop reasons), the safest way of iterating over a collection is using foreach.

Answer (score 1):

if you put break points on the for look and step through individual tasks.. see if await is actually awaiting. also put try / catch and see if any exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: There are no exceptions being thrown, and when I put breakpoints there they never get hit.

Comment: I just was able to isolate the code used to delete all the files by placing that code inside the OnNavigatedTo event and it worked. But I can't use it there. I need to place it in either Unloaded or, as you mentioned in my other question, the Suspending event - but the code doesn't work there and breakpoints aren't being hit when they're there.

Comment: why dont you create an async task using Task.Run and then inside that task, delete the files.. you can then call it from OnNavigatedTo